# Cookie not deleting

Tags: c#, cookies, visual-studio-2012, devexpress

System.Web.UI.Page oPageMy cookie is not deleting.  I took a look at several articles and everything looks great, just when I step through Visual Studio (or just run under localhost) in resopnse to a button click, my cookie stays.

For whatever it is worth, I am using Visual Studio 2012 with .Net 4.0.  I am debugging on localhost using the default IE (v9 on Win7/64 with all the latest updates).

```
public static void LoginUser(String strEmail, int iId, int iKeepDays)
{
    HttpCookie oCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");

    // Set the cookie value.
    oCookie.Secure = false;
    oCookie["Id"] = iId.ToString();
    oCookie["Email"] = strEmail;
    oCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(iKeepDays);

    // Add the cookie.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(oCookie);
}

public static void LogoutUser(System.Web.UI.Page oPage)
{
    // Get the cookie.
    HttpCookie oCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
    oCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
    if (null != oCookie)
    {
        // Remove the cookie.
        cCookies.RemoveCookie("myCookie");

        // Go back to the home page.
        if (oPage.IsCallback)
            ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback("/");
        else
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This function will be used to remove cookies value 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key"></param>
public static void RemoveCookie(String key)
{
    //get cookies value 
    HttpCookie oCookie = null;

    if (null != HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key])
    {
        oCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];

        // You cannt directly delte cookie you should set its expiry date to earlier date 
        oCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(oCookie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems obvious now that I am writing it and figured it out, however I can say that the answer was not that easy to come by, obvious or not.

The code above executes on the server, but the deletion of the cookie happens on the client.  Execution has to transfer to the client and then back to the server in order for the server to recognize that the cookie got deleted.

I was reading the data back within the same logout call, just in a different function.  Since accepted practice states to reset the cookie, the function wrote the cookie back.  The cookie was deleted and then came back.  It even got a new file name.  (I opened up the hidden cookie folder.)

My solution was to pass in the login state to that other function.  That resolved the cookie part.

Answer (score 0):

The `cCookies.RemoveCookie("myCookie");` line does not call your `RemoveCookie` method.  The line should be `RemoveCookie("myCookie");` instead.

Comment: I am just posting your comment.  You have to scroll down to see the RemoveCookie() method. It really is stumping me at the moment.  I am stepping into the line, where it says DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) and still the cookie remains.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger then it is one tough cookie

Comment: From the .Net code you will not be able to see the cookie get deleted.  When .Net sends back the response headers to the browser, you will see a "Set-Cookie" header with the expired cookie's date.  Then you should see the cookie get deleted by the browser.

Comment: We both wound up at the same conclusion at about the same time.  Thanks David!